# How prove this $\sin(2a)+\sin(2b)+\sin(2c)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sin a\cos b+2\sin b\cos c$

Tags: inequality

let $0<a<b<c<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, use the integral inequality show that
$$\sin(2a)+\sin(2b)+\sin(2c)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sin a\cos b+2\sin b\cos c$$

I know this problem can use The area of the geometry to solve it.and My teacher tell us can use integral to solve it too.maybe use Double integral

the PDF(page 4) give the area methods to solve this problem: can see:[link](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=ya62QWuTHTKbItsl2vMYEkHX3SUUM897o4KMQCYq4sIMezyLT94c9c5CbNmDL8auZ0e_ksZdNKiEPTILc4eYTk-d-LBUlcDU9ZnuMV7U9ke)
 let $$\angle AOD=x,\angle BOD=y,\angle COD=z,A(\cos x,\sin x),B(\cos y,\sin y)
C(\cos z,\sin z)$$
this picture three rectangular area sum is
$$I_1=2\sin x(\cos x-\sin y)+2\sin y(\cos y-\sin z)+2\sin z(\cos z-\sin x)$$
and the The area of the semicircle is $I_{2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,
so $$I_1<I_2\Longrightarrow  \sin(2a)+\sin(2b)+\sin(2c)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sin a\cos b+2\sin b\cos c$$

Thank you for you help

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your area argument suggest an immediate Riemann sum inequality?